# Bluetooth paired but not connected

Tags: 14.04, bluetooth

I managed (once) to get a pairing and connection and actually saw the files in the phone IMAGES directory, but could not copy them. Then I lost the connection. The only repeatable sequence I have found thus far is to REMOVE the pairing on the Ubuntu Bluetooth panel; reboot; then on the phone have it search and ADD; give it a password; then I get a bottom pop up that asks for the password... after which I sometimes briefly see Connected YES, until I try to do anything.

If I attempt to do this sequence without a reboot, I never get the bottom popup from Ubuntu requesting the password and the phone eventually times out in its query. Even a stop/start or restart bluetooth has no effect. The name of the phone and its MAC address appear in the /var/lib/bluetooth directory.

I have gone to the Shared Files panel and set it up as one of the others who have asked this same question was told to do.

If instead of an ADD on the phone, I try clicking the existing paired name on the phone, it says the connection must be initiated from the computer.

At no point is either side of this giving me any useful diagnostic information. It also seems a bit silly that I have to re-ask a question instead of adding on to an existing and nearly identical query since the information in those answers is obviously insufficiently general to cover my case.

Help would be much appreciated. I've spent hours on this today.

PS: I've also looked at things with hcitool but did not see anything that helped explain what is going on.

Not sure I see what this tells me, but since you ask:

```
$ lspci -knn | grep Net -A2; lsusb
00:19.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation 82579LM Gigabit Network Connection [8086:1502] (rev 04)
        Subsystem: Lenovo Device [17aa:21ce]
        Kernel driver in use: e1000e
--
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Centrino Advanced-N 6205 [Taylor Peak] [8086:0085] (rev 34)
        Subsystem: Intel Corporation Centrino Advanced-N 6205 AGN [8086:1311]
        Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 04f2:b217 Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd Lenovo Integrated Camera (0.3MP)
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0a5c:217f Broadcom Corp. BCM2045B (BDC-2.1)
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 147e:2016 Upek Biometric Touchchip/Touchstrip Fingerprint Sensor
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

More requested information:

```
$ dmesg | grep Blue
[    1.920369] usb 1-1.4: Product: Broadcom Bluetooth Device
[   56.522012] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.17
[   56.522029] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[   56.522036] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[   56.522038] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[   56.522042] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[   81.197106] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[   81.197109] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[   81.197116] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[   81.202182] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[   81.202190] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[   81.202194] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
```

and

```
$ rfkill list
0: tpacpi_bluetooth_sw: Bluetooth
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: no
1: hci0: Bluetooth
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: no
2: phy0: Wireless LAN
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: no
```

Just for completeness, the Control Panel bluetooth panel shows:

```
Bluetooth: ON
Visibility of "ubuntu-gnome-0": ON
Devices: SCH-R355
Connection: OFF
Paired: Yes
Type: Phone
Address: <A MAC ADDRESS>
```

Here is the output:

```
~$ usb-devices | awk '/217f/' RS=
T:  Bus=01 Lev=02 Prnt=02 Port=03 Cnt=02 Dev#=  4 Spd=12  MxCh= 0
D:  Ver= 2.00 Cls=e0(wlcon) Sub=01 Prot=01 MxPS=64 #Cfgs=  1
P:  Vendor=0a5c ProdID=217f Rev=07.48
S:  Manufacturer=Broadcom Corp
S:  Product=Broadcom Bluetooth Device
S:  SerialNumber=XXXXXXXXXXXX
C:  #Ifs= 4 Cfg#= 1 Atr=e0 MxPwr=0mA
I:  If#= 0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 3 Cls=e0(wlcon) Sub=01 Prot=01 Driver=btusb
I:  If#= 1 Alt= 0 #EPs= 2 Cls=e0(wlcon) Sub=01 Prot=01 Driver=btusb
I:  If#= 2 Alt= 0 #EPs= 2 Cls=ff(vend.) Sub=ff Prot=ff Driver=(none)
I:  If#= 3 Alt= 0 #EPs= 0 Cls=fe(app. ) Sub=01 Prot=01 Driver=(none)
```

Comment: lease [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2; lsusb` terminal command.

Comment: Please also add output of `dmesg | grep Blue` and `rfkill list`.

Comment: After a week of silence I'm getting worried that no one has any idea of the next thing for me to try...

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `usb-devices | awk '/217f/' RS=` terminal command.

Comment: Data you requested is now above.

Answer (score 0):

Check this [link](https://communities.intel.com/thread/62848). I had a similar problem and it got solved.

I could not connect / remove the device.
So I executed the following commands as **root**

```
rfkill unblock bluetooth
bluetoothctl
remove [Device]
```

And after that I paired it and it got connected.